# How can I access "Microsoft 365 Defender" -> Streaming API through Portal.Azure.com?

Tags: azure, microsoft365-defender

In my company I administrer many diffrent Azure tenants.
I log into my customers using a MyCustomer Portal.
When I click a customer in the portal I am transfered to https://portal.azure.com and logged in to the customer.

If I open a tab and enter the URL https://security.microsoft.com I will not be logged in as the customer.

I need to go to https://security.microsoft.com -> Settings -> Microsoft 365 Defender -> Streaming API and setup a export of some data for my customers.

How can I access "Streaming API" from
https://portal.azure.com ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the results as below:***

I tried to login to https://security.microsoft.com/ with another user account but it got logged with my account:

[image]

Note that: You must be able to login with customer account to the Security Center without any issue.

**To resolve the issue, try the below:**

- Clear the caches and cookies as you might be logged in with other account.
- Check whether in the Azure Portal you are signed with the correct user and check the TenantID.
- Try logging-in to the https://security.microsoft.com/ in the Incognito Browser.

***After clearing the cache, I am able to login with the correct account as below:***

[image]

AFAIK, accessing Streaming API from Azure Portal is currently not possible.

**Reference:**

[Microsoft 365 Defender integration with Microsoft Sentinel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sentinel/microsoft-365-defender-sentinel-integration#advanced-hunting-event-collection)